# str_replace() not working properly

Tags: php, str-replace

Good Morning,

I'm currently trying to replace some strings from an xml document, some of them are working well but some others aren't and I can't figure out why... can this problem come from the fact the xml was written using Microsoft Word ?

Here is my PhP code:

```
<?php
   $document = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/../wwwPublic/vehicule_ci/assets/res/annulation.xml");

   $document = str_replace('@ville@', "test_ville", $document);
   $document = str_replace('@date@', date('d/m/Y'), $document);
   $document = str_replace('@emetteur@', "test_emetteur", $document);

   $handle = fopen(utf8_decode($documentPath), "w");
   fwrite($handle, $document);
   fclose($handle);

   echo $document;
?>
```

Here is the output:

```
test_ville le 20/04/2017Ref Client : @emetteur@N° Voucher :ÉmetteurDestinataireNom :@emetteur@
```

as you can see, the "ville" and the "date" are being replaced correctly, but the "emetteur" isn't..., If someone got an idea, I'll take it.

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide a sample value for `$document` (before the replacements) with which the problem can be reproduced?

Comment: I can spot two main warning signs: 1) You don't make any reference to the concept of text encoding 2) You are using `utf8_encoding()`.

Comment: Can you update your xml content into your question?
I have tried the part `$document = str_replace('@emetteur@', "test_emetteur", $document);` and it works fine.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález : I tryed the utf8_encoding() to test if it have changed something

Comment: As the manual says, `utf8_decode()` "converts a string with ISO-8859-1 characters encoded with UTF-8 to single-byte ISO-8859-1". Not sure what you want to test that way. Have you even opened the XML file to see encoding it's using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely due to the fact that the document was written in word. I've experienced errors like this before too. Maybe you need to convert the document using the iconv function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: Thank you for your reply, In wich format do you advise me to convert it ?

Comment: Your best bet is converting to Utf-8, another suggestion of mine would be to use DomDocument to query the xml node you want to replace, rather than using str_replace,

Comment: My main goal is to write the edited text to a .doc document by keeping the design, can I make it too if I directly edit the xml ?

Comment: @Alex I'm not 100% sure. you'd have to try it out. Otherwise something like [this](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) might be able to help you edit the document.

Comment: I have found the problem, @emetteur@ never occurs in your file. It seems to occur as 
`<w:t>@</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Helv" w:h-ansi="Helv" w:cs="Helv"/><wx:font wx:val="Helv"/><w:b/><w:b-cs/><w:color w:val="000000"/><w:sz w:val="20"/><w:sz-cs w:val="20"/></w:rPr><w:t>emetteur</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Helv" w:h-ansi="Helv" w:cs="Helv"/><wx:font wx:val="Helv"/><w:b/><w:b-cs/><w:color w:val="000000"/><w:sz w:val="20"/><w:sz-cs w:val="20"/></w:rPr><w:t>@</w:t>`

Ensure you are using the same font

Comment: Thank you very much mate, you fixed it :)